# Find series expansion of $f(x)=x^2\tan^{-1}(x^3)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, taylor-expansion, power-series

I was requested  to find the power expansion of $f(x)=x^2\tan^{-1}(x^3)$ and, since I'm new to power series, was wondering if my procedure is correct. I explain it by parts.

$i)$ Consider the power expansion of $\frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1}(x^3)$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}(x^3) = \frac{3x^2}{1+x^6} = 3x^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^6)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \space 3x^{6n+2}$$

$ii)$ Clearly,

$$f(x) = x^2\tan^{-1}(x^3) = x^2 \int \frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1}(x^3) dx = x^2 \int \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \space 3x^{6n+2}dx$$

due to step $i$.

$iii)$

$$f(x)=x^2\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \space 3x^{6n+2}dx = x^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \space \frac{3x^{6n+3}}{6n+3} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \space \frac{3x^{6n+5}}{6n+3} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \space \frac{x^{6n+5}}{2n+1}$$

$$=\frac{x^{11}}{9}  - \frac{x^{17}}{15}  + \frac{x^{23}}{21}  - \frac{x^{29}}{27}  +...   $$

*Note*. The series convergence radius will be $|x^6| < 1 = (-1, 1)$

Is this solution correct? I tried checking with online series expansion calculators, but they seem incapable of handling the particular problem.

Comment: $-1^n$ is different from $(-1)^n$.

Comment: What level of rigor (in the sense of mathematical proof) are you required to use? If it's simply a matter of formal algebraic manipulation, then simply substitute $x^3$ for $x$ in the expansion for $\tan^{-1}x$ and then increase each of the resulting exponents of $x$ by $2.$ Regarding "I tried checking with online series expansion calculators", see [this WolframAlpha calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+%28x%5E2%29*%28arctan+%28x%5E3%29%29+at+x+%3D+0+to+order+20).

Comment: The **radius** of convergence is a number. The **region** of convergence is a set.

Comment: Also, you got the right series, but in the last step you miscalculated the first terms: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n  \frac{x^{6n+5}}{2n+1}  \ne \frac{x^{11}}{9}  - \frac{x^{17}}{15}  + \frac{x^{23}}{21}  - \frac{x^{29}}{27}  +\cdots$$

Comment: It's not wrong but I feel that by differentiating $\tan^{-1} (x^3)$ instead of just $\tan^{-1}$ added complications. Instead you could substitute after you've integrated the series term by term in the same way you took care of the $x^2$ product after you expanded the series.

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan^{-1} z= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{z^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$
So $$x^2\tan^{-1} x^3=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{6k+5}}{2k+1}.$$